# Изменить заголовок navigation bar swift

Tags: swift

Есть несколько окон, нужно в "шапке", тобишь в `navigation bar` добавить `label`, который будет для всех окон одинаков, но может быть изменен. Сделал так

```
let longTitleLabel = UILabel()
longTitleLabel.text = String(score)
longTitleLabel.sizeToFit()
let Item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: longTitleLabel)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = Item
```

переменную `score` храню локально в бд, проблема в том, что, когда я его меняю в одном окне в другом оно не обновляется (в принципе, логично), как можно обновить `label` во всех окнах ? сейчас у меня добавление `label` стоит на `viewDidLoad`, но т.к использую `navigation control`, то этот метод срабатывает 1 раз, как решить данную проблему ?

Comment: Переместите добавление в viewWillAppear

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk спасибо